# Remove only LF in txt file

Tags: php, regex, text, notepad++

I need to remove only the `LF`, not `CRLF`. Any idea about that?

I can use PHP, notepad++, shell script, etc

[image]

Comment: You need to remove LF, or to replace it with CRLF?

Comment: All LF or only the one without a CR before?

Comment: @stema I need to remove all LF without CR before. Only this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In notepad++

Try this : `(?<!\r)\n`

Make sure to set the option for regular expression in the search options, hope it helps

Comment: Worked for me. Weird thing is that reversing it to `\r(?<!\n)` did not work for me to find only CR not followed by LF... But I then tried this variation that did work: `\r^`

Comment: Or this one also seems to do the trick for finding lone CRs: `\r[^\n]+` . This one may be better as it does not depend on 'line-end', which is fuzzy for lone CR's anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookbehind.

```
$str = preg_replace("#(?<!\r)\n#", '', $str);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ty9XWn)

Answer (score 1):

LF stands for line feed character, which is ASCII 10 or 0x0A or "\n" (in PHP). So just do

`search_replace( "\n", '', $text)`

Pleae note CRLF are in fact two characters CR (carriage return) + LF. If you remove LF, you will still have CR (if any) in your text.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove just standalone LFs but keep CRLF then above code is wrong as it would turn CRLF into CRs. Use `preg_replace()` to do that

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\\r)\\n+(?!\\r)/", '', $text);
```

If for any reasons you'd like not to use `preg_replace()` (but do use it anyway), then you can try this dumb approach:

```
// save CRLFs by replacing with some text that does 
$tmp = str_replace("\r\n", 'S0m3L1k3LyUn1Qu3T3X7', $text);

// get rid of LFs
$tmp = str_replace("\n", '', $tmp );

// restore CRLFs
$text = str_replace('S0m3L1k3LyUn1Qu3T3X7', "\r\n", $tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++, you use Search/Replace, tick extended (lower-left) and replace

```
\n
```

by nothing.

Comment: \n only affects LF, \r would affect CR. \r\n would affect CRLF ;).

But yeah, it would affect the LR in CRLR, too.

Comment: i think this won't work as i need. If i search \n also find the LF in CRLF.